# Unable to properly add a file header on a POST request using axios in a node application

Tags: node.js, http, curl, post, axios

I'm trying to convert the following curl syntax to node.js using axios:

```
curl -X POST "https://my-target-baseURL.com/elements/api/files? 
path=%2Fmy-file&folderId=1234" 
-H "accept: application/json" 
-H "Authorization: SomeHeader 1234, OtherHeader 1234" 
-H "content-type: multipart/form-data" 
-F "file=@my-file.png;type=image/png"
```

In oder to convert this, I'm doing the following.

```
    const fileInfo = path.parse(req.file.filename)
    const fileFullName = fileInfo.name + fileInfo.ext
    const folder_id = req.query.id
    const readFile = util.promisify(fs.readFile)
    const fullPath = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'someDirectory', fileFullName)
    const file_to_upload = await readFile(`${fullPath}`)

    try {
      const uploaded_file = await axios.post(`${my-target-baseURL.com}/elements/api/files?path=%2F${fileFullName}&folderId=${folder_id}`,
      file_to_upload,
      { headers: { 'accept': 'application/json', Authorization: `SomeHeader xyz, OtherHeader xyz`, 
      'content-type':'multipart/form-data',},
    })
      console.log('uploaded_file: ', uploaded_file.data)
    }
    catch(error) {
        throw new Error(error)
    }
```

Upon doing this, I get a 500 error (`Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): Error: Error: Request failed with status code 500`).

One small thing to mention here is that the way I'm reading the file works fine. The reason I say this is because this piece of code used to read the file just like this and hit another API and got a response without any sort of problem.

I'm unable to find what's causing this problem. Is there something wrong with the way I'm converting the curl to the axios call? Am I doing the conversion for `-F "file=@my-file.png;type=image/png"` correctly?

Answer (score 0):

This looks good to me, can you copy your request as CURL when you try it and add the result?

Also it's cleaner to break header out into something like

```
const headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json', 
    'Authorization': `SomeHeader xyz, OtherHeader xyz`,
    'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data'
    }
```

and then do

```
await axios.post(`${my-target-baseURL.com}/elements/api/files?path=%2F${fileFullName}&folderId=${folder_id}`,
      file_to_upload,
      {headers});
```

Comment: what I find strange is this. Let's say I'm inside a directory called desktop/wallpapers. If I cd into that directory and then execute the curl command, it works. It doesn't work from anywhere else. 

And about the way I'm doing it in the code, I have a folder `someDirectory` in my project, where I have the file. The `file_to_upload` on the code comes from that folder. So I am ensuring that the axios call sees the file properly. So the problem is definitely with the way I'm handling `-F "file=@my-file.png;type=image/png"`. Any thoughts?